# Confusion between two clauses

Tags: nouns, adverbials

Could this clause be interpreted in both Adverbial clause and noun clause?

> Maria will tell you when David gets home - **In this one, Maria says that she will tell someone when David gets home.**
>
> Maria will tell you when David gets home - **In this one, Maria says that she will tell her friend something only when David gets home.**

These both are examples of adverbial and noun clauses, the first one is a noun clause (When David gets home is the direct object of the verb tell)
and the second one is an adverbial clause.

Could they be possible confused? I guess the only way to differ both would be if it were: Maria will tell you it when David gets home - since "it" is the direct object.

Comment: Yes, they are ambiguous. Whatever the meaning, grammatically the expression "when David gets home" is not an object (the object of "tell" is "you"), but a temporal adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @Billj - I think you are wrong about the object. **You** is the **indirect object** of the verb **Tell**.

Comment: In "Maria will tell you when David gets home",  there is only one object, "you", so it must be a direct object. The phrase "when David gets home" is not an object, but an adjunct. It informs us when Maria will be telling you.

Comment: But, a sentence can't have an indirect object without also having a direct object.

Comment: @BillJ - When David gets home is the direct object of the verb Tell, noun clauses function as *subjects, direct objects, indirect objects, predicate nouns, adjective complements and object of preposition.* 

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Noun-Clauses.htm

Therefore: **Maria will tell when David gets home to you

Maria will tell you when David gets home **

They are the same.

Comment: Not so. In any case, it's not a noun clause (even if there were such a thing); it's a clause functioning as an adjunct that informs us when Maria will be telling you something. Some grammars would analyse it as a PP headed by "when". I too prefer that analysis.

Comment: @BillJ: in Haseo's first interpretation, "when David gets home" is indeed a noun clause, and the direct object of "tell". Haseo's gloss on it was not very clear, but their analysis is spot-on, in the question and in comments. In the second interpretation it is, as you say, an adjunct.

Comment: @Colin Fine I don't agree. Such clauses (or PP's) simply don't function as objects.

Comment: @BillJ: Really? What's its function in "I know when he came home"? or similarly in "I saw what you did"

Comment: @Colin Fine "When he came home" is an interrogative content clause (embedded question). The meaning is "I know the answer to the question 'When did he come home?"'. The clause functions as complement to "know".

Comment: @BillJ - I think you should review these topics: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Noun-Clauses.htm
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbial-Clauses.htm

This will explain to you what we are talking about. 

Quick explanation: When he comes home is a noun clause functioning as an object. It would be the same as: Maria will tell you IT ( It = When he comes home ). 

In the other interpretation: Maria will tell you when he comes home could be easily inverted to imply the inteded meaning: When he comes home, I will tell you that.

Check the links I attached here to understand.

Comment: As is often the case on ELU, different analyses are here being stated as incontrovertibly true. At least references should be added to support individual interpretations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be interpreted in both ways, yes. If you want to avoid confusion between the two, perhaps consider rearranging the second instance to: "When David gets home, Maria will tell you". This has a stronger emphasis on the time (the official word for this escapes me). The English language relies heavily on context and emphasis to convey different meanings so I think you can use these without too much worry of confusion.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought so. 
Since adverbial clauses are dependent clauses (.i.e: can't stand alone), inverting the placement and adding comma would imply that it's an adverbial clause: **When David gets home, I will tell you**.